# Regex to match possibly-escaped quotes

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I'm trying to write a regex to match single quotes, which may be escaped. A matched quote should have an even number of backslashes before it (an odd number means that the quote is escaped). For example, in these five strings:

```
'quotes should be matched'
\'quotes should NOT be matched\'
\\'quotes should be matched\\'
\\\'quotes should NOT be matched\\\'
\\\\'quotes should be matched\\\\'
```

Here is the regex that I have:

```
(?<=[^\\](?:\\\\)*)'
```

However, this does not match anything in the above example. I find this strange because removing the `*` from the regex matches the quotes with two backslashes, as it should:

`(?<=[^\\](?:\\\\))'` matches `\\'`

Comment: Regex is usually not the best tool for matching like this

Comment: I really don't have a choice in my situation. Just out of curiosity, what would my alternatives be?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: It doesn't work when you add the `*` because that portion is within your lookbehind, and most regex engines do not support variable-length lookbehinds (i.e., can't include quantifiers like `?`, `*`, `+`, `{n,m}`).

Comment: @Joel it depends on many factors; like if this is a CSV file there is probably already a CSV parser built in to whatever language you are using.  If it's a unique data set, you may have to create your own parser.

Comment: @chepner I'm using php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, it's not possible to match just the `'`. This is because you can't have dynamic length lookbehinds as Wiseguy pointed out.

The following regex would match the correct `'` AND any `\`s leading up to it however. Not sure if this will be of any use..

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*'
```

Matches an arbitrary number of double `\`s not preceded by a `\` and followed by a `'`.

Comment: You can sort of simulate variable-length lookbehinds with `\K`.  `(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*\K'` matches just the `'`.  http://regexr.com?340ef